# Multiple jQuery Selector Not Registering Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to register a click event with jQuery. This works for me:

```
$('ul.main-menu li').click(function() {
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

But what I need is for this to work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.email-refresh, #loadMoreMessages, ul.main-menu li', function() {
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

When I click on the `.email-refresh` and `#loadMoreMessages` elements, the click event works. However, when I click on a `ul.main-menu li` element, the click event does not work.

What do I need to do in order to get this click event working? I don't really understand why it works in my first line of code but not in my second.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I will try. Give me a sec

Comment: @MilindAnantwar on jsfiddle it works but on my webpage it does not. Now I am really confused.

Comment: so, do you have a <ul class="main-menu"> <li> ... </li> </ul>. correct?

Comment: check for the markup of ul li elements. i guess it is broken.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3noms7vc/

Comment: I am just so confused how my first chunk of code in my posting works but the second does not. The HTML of `<ul class="main-menu"> <li> ... </li> </ul>` is not changing at all.

Comment: Have you got another click or mousedown handler that is preventing bubbling?

Comment: @Phylogenesis nope, this is my only click handler on the page.

Comment: silly question: does this code works for you?     `$('.email-refresh, #loadMoreMessages, ul.main-menu li').click(function() {
      alert('Clicked');
    });`

Comment: @pumpkinzzz This works for the `email-refresh` click and for the `ul.main-menu li` click events. However, it does not work for the `#loadMoreMessages` click. This is because my `#loadMoreMessages` element is being loaded dynamically after the initial dom is loaded. That is why I just put all 3 selectors in the `$(document).on('click')` handler.

Comment: does`$('.email-refresh, #loadMoreMessages').click(function() { alert('Clicked email or more messages'); });$(' ul.main-menu li').click(function() { alert('Clicked ul li'); });` work ??

Comment: @Billy Yep, those both work. It is just when I add `'ul.main-menu li'` to the `'.email-refresh, #loadMoreMessages'` event handler when it does not work.

Comment: is this menu inside an iframe? anyway, i suggest to use a common class for those elements, so u can just do `$('.common_class').click(function() { alert('Clicked'); });`

Comment: try it this way `$(' ul.main-menu li, .email-refresh, #loadMoreMessages').click etc.......` so the selector by tag, then class then id, just incase it's a specifity thing. does it work this way ??

Comment: @Billy Nope, this did not work unfortunately. I tried doing this before posting and it did not work. I just tried again, it's a no go.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz This is Not in an iFrame. I will try assigning a common call right now to see if that will solve the issue.

Comment: stumped me, I can't reproduce the problem,sorry

Comment: @pumpkinzzz I just tried the common class method but that did not work either. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: this is really weird. using browser console type: `$('ul.main-menu li', document)` and see if it returns your <ul> element or empty

Comment: @pumpkinzzz I know, this is extremely weird to me as well. I have never come across this problem before. Here is the screenshot of my console after running `$('ul.main-menu li', document)` http://imgur.com/DTDfC1j

Comment: it looks like correct! ... i m running out of solutions here xD

Comment: @pumpkinzzz I know. Me too. I am trying some other stuff. Will let everyone know how it goes once I find a solution! Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: make sure is not a CSS issue, like some layer that goes over the menu and grab the click event (see this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/3noms7vc/1/ )

Comment: Did u try `.main-menu>li` ? Ideally common class should wrk :-)

Comment: It could be due you had other elements with absolute position and you clicked on it instead.Though this question asked 4 years ago.